# Elastic search - best way for multiple updates index?

Tags: elasticsearch

I'm integrating with external system.

From it I have 3 files:

- `customer_data.csv`
- `address_data.csv`
- `additional_customer_data.csv`

**Order in each of them can be random.**

There is:

- relation one to many (`customer_data` => `addresses`) but I am interested only in one address with specified kind.
- one to one (`customer_data`  => `additional_customer_data`)

Goal:

`Merge files together and put it in one index in` Elastic search`.`

Additional info:

-`each file has circa 1 million records`

-`this operation will be done each night`

-`data is used only for search purposes`

Options:

a) I thought about:

1. Parse and add to ES first file
2. Do the same from next and update document created in point one

Looks very inefficient.

b) another way:

1. parse and add first file to relational data base
2. do same with another fields and update records from point one
3. Propagate data to ES

Can you see another options?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you have a normalized relational data structure with 1 to n relationships in those CSV files like that:

`customer_data.csv`

```
Id;Name;AdressId;AdditionalCustomerDataId;...
0;Mike;2;1;...
```

`address_data.csv`

```
Id;Street;City;...
....
2;Abbey Road;London;...
```

`additional_customer_data.csv`

```
Id;someData;...
...
1;data;...
```

In that case, I would denormalize those in a preprocessing step into one single CSV and use that to upload them to ES. For avoiding downtime, you can then use aliases.
Preprocessing can be done in any language, but probably converting the CSVs into a sqlite table will be the fastest.

I wouldn't choose a strategy to create just half of the document and add the additional information later, as you probably need to reindex afterwards.

However, maybe you can tell us more about the requirements and the external system, cause this doesn't seem to be a great solution.

Comment: I updated post. If you want to know more let me know what exactly.